# HTML Email stripping out characters

Tags: html, email

I currently have a HTML email which I am sending through PHP. The styling and everything with it is fine, the problem is that it is stripping out some characters from my text that is contained within the email.

Here are my headers

```
$from = "noreply@myemail.com";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers  = "From: ".$from."\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Has anybody got any ideas? Thanks in advance

Here's the code in full. Sometimes its spaces, or it will add a space in the middle of the word. Other times it will miss characters out of a word

```
$from = "noreply@mydomain.co.uk";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers  .= "From: ".$from."\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$body = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <!-- Facebook sharing information tags --></head><body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #000000;width: 100%;"><center><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="backgroundTable" style="margin: 0;padding: 0;background-color: #000000;height: 100%;width: 100%;"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateContainer" style="border: 1px solid #000000;background-color: #000000;"><tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateHeader" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-bottom: 0;"> <tr> <td class="headerContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;color: #202020;font-family: georgia;font-size: 34px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;padding: 0;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;"><a target="_blank" name="sw" href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk" href="" title=""><img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/header.jpg" style="max-width: 600px;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext></a></td></tr></table></td></tr> <tr><td align="center" valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" id="templateBody"><tr> <td valign="top" class="bodyContent" style="border-collapse: collapse;background-color: #000000;"> <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Content \ --> <table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td valign="top" style="border-collapse: collapse;"> <div mc:edit="std_content00" style="color: #AC9366;font-family: georgia;font-size: 14px;line-height: 150%;text-align: left;"> <h3 class="h3" style="color: #C0B391;display: block;font-family: georgia;font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;line-height: 100%;margin-top: 0;margin-right: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;margin-left: 0;text-align: left;">Hi Aaron,</h3> <strong>Thanks for registering with us.</strong><br><p style="font-style:italic;">At Wicked, we believe you can get lots of pleasure by sharing. So we\'ll be sharing the details of our launch with you, plus some wonderfully wicked behind the scenes coverage of our photography shoot, featuring our luxury lingerie collection designed exclusively by <a href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/interviews/wicked/" target="_blank" name="leanna" style="color: #C0B391;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;">Leanne Brooke</a>.<br><br> We\'ll also give you the chance to win invitations to our VIP launches (in London &amp; Leeds), as well as having one of the first ever SW lingerie pieces, made to measure for you, by Leanne. <br><br> Until then... <br><br> SW.</p><br><br><br><br> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/wearewicked" target="_blank" name="swtwitter" style="color: #C0B391;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/t-email.jpg" alt="" style="border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;"></a> &nbsp; <a href="https://www.facebook.com/mypage" target="_blank" name="swfacebook" style="color: #C0B391;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/f-email.jpg" alt="" style="border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;"></a>  &nbsp; <a href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk" target="_blank" name="swsite" style="color: #C0B391;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/sw-email.png" alt="" style="border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;"></a>  &nbsp; <a href="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/blog" target="_blank" name="swblog" style="color: #C0B391;font-weight: normal;text-decoration: underline;"><img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/blog.png" alt="" style="border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;display: inline;"></a></h3></div></td> </tr> </table></td> </tr> </table></td></tr><tr><td align="center" valign="bottom" style="border-collapse: collapse;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600"> <tr> <td style="border-collapse: collapse;"><img src="http://www.mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/footer.jpg" style="max-width: 600px;border: 0;height: auto;line-height: 100%;outline: none;text-decoration: none;" id="headerImage campaign-icon" mc:label="header_image" mc:edit="header_image" mc:allowdesigner mc:allowtext> </td> </tr> </table> <!-- // End Template Footer \ --> </td> </tr> </table> <br> </td> </tr> </table> </center> </body></html>';

 mail($email, 'My Subject line', $body, $headers);
```

(see [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1ySkc79z) for easier reading)

Comment: Can you post more details about the "stripping out some characters" part?

Comment: which characters are missing? where do you set the content?

Comment: Its text contained within the email, sometimes it will remove a character or space and this varies from email to email.

Comment: What characters are being stripped out? Can you show some of the problematic code?

Comment: ok, then provide some of the code where the content will be set.

Comment: I think you should also change
$headers  = "From: ".$from."\r\n";  too
$headers  .= "From: ".$from."\r\n"; (add the '.')

Comment: please provide full php script to help. especially where the content will be set. or how do you do this?

Comment: @frgtv10 Hi I've added the code above, can you see anything as to why this might be happening? Thanks

Comment: I'd be a little suspicious of the fact that your e-mail body claims to be UTF-8 but your headers claim to be ISO-8859-1. Strikes me as a recipe for trouble...

Answer (score 0):

If your content has lines longer than some 1000 characters, most mail servers will reformat it by force. Wrap your content in quoted-printable or base64 encoding, or simply insert line breaks on whitespace characters every 75 characters or so.

Also concur with the comment that ISO 8859-1 seems suspicious here, although it doesn't seem to affect this particular message. But in this day and age, any code you write should use UTF-8.